# Killing vector fields are affine

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$. We say that $X$ is affine if $L_X \nabla = 0$, where $\nabla$ is the Riemannian connection on $M$. How do we prove that Killing vector fields are affine?

I know that if $X$ is a Killing vector field, then $L_X g = 0$, which is equivalent to saying that for all other smooth vector fields $Y$ and $Z$, $$g(\nabla_Y X, Z) + g(Y, \nabla_Z X) = 0. $$ We can also say that the flow of $X$ preserves $g$, that is, $(\phi_X^t)^*g = g$, where $\phi_X^t$ is the flow of $X$ at time $t$. However, I don't know how to relate this to the Lie derivative of the connection.

I also read about a formula relating the coefficients of $L_X \nabla$ with the curvature tensor (in local coordinates). However, I would like to avoid using it.

Comment: There is a formula for the Levi-Civita connection in terms of the metric, first order derivatives and Lie brackets. It is called the Koszul formula. Using that, it should be easy to prove.

Comment: You mean the Koszul formula, saying that $$2g(\nabla_Y X, Z) = L_X(g(Y,Z)) + L_Y(g(X,Z)) - L_Z(g(X,Y)) - g([X,Y],Z) - g([Y,Z],X) + g([Z,X],Y) $$?

Comment: But how would I use it?

Comment: yes exactly. A Killing field preserves the metric, it is an infinitesimal isometry of the Riemannian manifold. Being a vector field, it is also an infinitesimal diffeomorphism of the underlying smooth manifold, so it preserves the Lie bracket basically. Well, I mean that the corresponding flow preserves the metric and the Lie bracket respectively.

Comment: By the way, a connection on a smooth manifold is not a tensor, though the difference between two connections is a tensor.

Comment: Yes, I realized it now. What do you mean by saying that the flow of the vector field preserves the Lie bracket?

Comment: I think you can apply the flow at $t$ to the Koszul formula. Since the flow preserves $g$ and Lie brackets, it would show that the pullback of the LC connection also satisfies the Koszul formula, and so must be equal to the LC connection. This should work, though keeping track of the basepoint can be annoying.

Comment: A more or less equivalent way is to show that the pullback of the LC connection under the flow associated to a Killing field is torsion-free and metric, then invoque the so-called fundamental theorem of Riemannian geometry.

Comment: By "the flow preserves the Lie bracket", I mean that if you have two vector fields, say $Y$ and $Z$, you take their Lie bracket and then you push forward by the flow at $t$, it is the same as pushing forward $Y$ and $Z$ and then taking the Lie bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, there is a simple anwser: As you noted, the local flows of a Killing filed all are isometries, so they preserve the metric. Since the Levi-Civita connection is naturally derived from the metric, it is also preserved by the local flows of a Killing field. (You can make this explict either via the Koszul-formula mentioned in the comments. Alternatively, you can observe that pulling back the Levi-Civita connection along an isometry, you obtain a torsion free connection that is compatible with the metric. Then the result follows from uniqueness of the Levi-Civita connection.) The simplest definition of an affine vector field actually is that all local flows prefer the connection. If you want to make to phrase this in terms of a Lie derivative, you first have to say what exactly you mean by the Lie derivative of a linear connection (since this is not a tensor field). I guess, the easiest way to get to this is to differentiate the property that the connection is preserved by the local flows ...